# Accidentally deleted Ubuntu system partition during attempted Windows installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

During a foolish attempt at installing Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 12.10 on a separate drive for some lab work, I accidentally deleted (not formatted) the wrong disk and immediately after realizing what I had done stopped the installation. So now nothing is installed and I am left with

```
grub rescue>
```

I know my files are still there. How do I go about putting everything back in its place?

Would it be easier to continue with my plans to install Windows 7 on the right disk and recover the partitions from there?

Or should I recover my Ubuntu 12.10 system first and then attempt the Windows 7 install after with more caution?

Comment: Well, if you proceed you may loose your data. So I suggest recovering the partition. Have a look at this link from ubuntu.com: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so one good thing is you stopped the install.
You can now do two things:
1>Get another computer with Windows installed and connect your hard drive to it. Then go to http://www.active-undelete.com/ and try using their soft. I'm not sure it will support ext3 or ext4 type partitions but it is worth a try...

OR

2> Burn yourself a live cd/usb of http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org and see if it works for you.

Also checkout the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery page. Hope the links were helpful. Tell me in comment if any of them worked.