# Lost Ubuntu partition after reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I recently had to reinstall Windows 7 over a dual boot. My Ubuntu partition is no longer accessible. It still seems to show up when I use gparted from live USB. However, it's unallocated space. I don't know how to go about recovering the partition. If only I could browse through or grab some of the data I've temporarily lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've been looking through your boot-repair log. I don't see any unallocated space there. Could you please clarify, what makes you think so?

Comment: @MadMike there was no ext4 partition

Comment: When I run Ubuntu Live from USB, then GParted, I can see the unallocated chunk of space that used to function as my linux OS. Also, when I run testdisk, it will do the search and I can see and navigate through the directories that are apparently mostly still there...?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to have it _back_ and functioning, but the only data I'm interested in saving is personal, like browser bookmarks, photos and images, videos, downloads, and tomboy notes.

Comment: Related: [Accidentally deleted Ubuntu system partition during attempted Windows installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352839/accidentally-deleted-ubuntu-system-partition-during-attempted-windows-installati)

Answer (score 1):

Try `testdisk` it will recover your datas from deleted partition. Download testdisk from [**here**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and the step by step tutorial [**here**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)
.

Comment: Running testdisk didn't help me repair becaaause I don't know enough about what I'm doing. I ran testdisk from a usb flash drive with Ubuntu Rescue Remix--where can I find the log to post for more help? I got through the "Deeper Search."

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data