# Need help after accidentally deleting partition!

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I had Ubuntu on a partition with important files and I accidentally deleted the partition with Ubuntu and installed Windows on that partition.

I used disktest in live Ubuntu to get files from different partitions back but the one with Windows currently installed I had no luck. Should I uninstall Windows and then try to get files from the partition back that had Ubuntu installed?

Please help, these files are really important! The Windows installation is on the drive I need to return!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally deleted Ubuntu system partition during attempted Windows installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352839/accidentally-deleted-ubuntu-system-partition-during-attempted-windows-installati) and [Deleted Partition Recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery)

Answer (score 0):

The data on an already *overwritten* partition is almost definitely lost. You can try [data restoring software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery) or a specialized service but the chance you ever get all the original data intact is low. (Note that there is no accepted answer to the [possible duplicate questions found by karel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025123/please-need-help-after-accidentally-deleting-partition/1025135#comment1665593_1025123).)

> Should I uninstall the windows and then try to get files from the partition back that had Ubuntu installed?

You should *avoid* any write operations on the partition. There is nothing like uninstalling an OS, you would normally just overwrite it. However, this involves additional writes, so **don’t proceed** if you ever want to restore your data.

There is a much more reliable way to restore lost data, so I must ask you…
**Do you have any backup of your data?**

> There are two groups of people: Those who backup and those who haven’t lost any data yet.

According to my experience, a self-experienced data loss is really the strongest argument for starting to backup. If you haven’t been a member of the first group yet, I hope to welcome you there very soon.